# libffi and libp11-kit - no version information available

Tags: apt, shared-library

Every time I update the package sources list with:

```
sudo apt update
```

I get many lines of code like this:

```
/usr/lib/apt/methods/https: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0)
```

How can I solve this problem about dynamic libraries?

Comment: try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/how-do-i-check-package-version-using-apt-get-aptitude

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove problematic library by

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7
```

and then reinstall it using official repositories by

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libffi7
```